# geeglm y ~ x1 + I(x^2)

Tags: generalized-linear-model

In `glm` if a model is specified as

```
geeglm(qsmk ~ sex + race + age + I(age*age) , 
             family=binomial, data=data,
             id=id, corstr="independence")
```

What does the function `I` indicate, `I(age^2)` or `I(age*age)` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I()` means "as is" (see `?I`): this is needed because operators such as `^` and `*` have different meanings in a formula context than when they are doing regular computation. `I(age^2)` and `I(age*age)` are equivalent; they both mean to add an "age-squared" term to the model. If the formula contained unprotected `age^2` or `age*age` terms, it would denote the interaction of `age` with itself (or, "the main effect of `age` plus the interaction of `age` with itself").  The interaction of any variable with itself is defined as the original variable (i.e. `age^2` is equivalent to `age` in a formula context; so is `age*age`, because `age+age^2` -> `age+age` -> `age`).